# Go back to the previous page document selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

am trying to crawl g maps when I load the results in an array and pass then to a for loop to click and collect data then go back to the result page and continue it gives me

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

am here

```
for result in results:
    
    result.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-item-id="merchant"]')
        
        is_claimed = "no"
    except NoSuchElementException:
        is_claimed = "yes"
    print(is_claimed)
    driver.back()
```

Comment: You can't do it this way. You have to get the number of elements to loop and then xpath to the index.If you leave a page the elements will no longer be useable.

Comment: @arundeepchohan thanks I implemented your solution it worked !!

Comment: If you're trying to create a crawler, selenium might not be the right tool for you.